# Is there a way to cast the type of a destructured prop in the arguments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, casting, material-ui

I am using Material UI FixedSizeList. As per doc I render the rows in the renderRow function and pass it as a child to the component.

The function receives (index, style, data, scrolling) as arguments from the FixedSizeList component as defined in the ListChildComponentProps from Material UI.

The **data** argument is defined as **any** and is the array of all data provided. I would like to cast it to MyCustomType type.

I can do it as shown in the commented line but what wondering if it is possible to cast the type already in the function definition (1st line).

```
const renderRow = ({ index, style, data }: ListChildComponentProps) => {

// const { index, style, data }: { index: number; style: CSSProperties; data: MyCustomType[] } = props;

  return (
    <ListItem key={index} style={style}>
      <MyComponent rowData={data[index]} key={index} />
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

I think I understand what you are trying to do now. What about this:

```
import React from "react";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

type MyProps = Omit<ListChildComponentProps, 'data'> & { data: string };

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<MyProps> = ({ index, style, data }) => {
  // data is over type string now
 return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

Comment: MyComponent is already set up that way. I was wondering about the casting from "any" to "MyCustomType" in the 1st line where I destructure the props.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But what I am asking has nothing to do with MyComponent. You can delete MyComponent from the question and the question would remain the same. Maybe as an example, let's say before the return statement I want to console log an attribute of "data" but since data is of type any I have no type safety or intellisense.

Comment: If the parent component only passes down an `any[]` then you will have no type safety on it, unless the library allows you to specify a generic type.

Comment: Hence the second line where I "cast" the data prop to MyCustomType[]. And my question is, could I somehow do this in the 1st line already.

Comment: You can do it with `Omit<ListChildComponentProps, 'data'> & { data: string };`, it will give you intellisense but it won't provide any type safety

Comment: Thanks. I can live with this. If you write it as its own answer I will accept it.